# Input window doesn't get recognized using XPath

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# Set up the webdriver (you need to have the appropriate browser driver installed, like chromedriver)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Open myguichet.lu
driver.get("https://www.myguichet.lu")

#Time for me to log in into the page
time.sleep(60)

# Find the search box using XPath and input "1000"
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='fieldN20DA0']")
search_box.send_keys("1000")

# Wait for a few seconds to see the result
time.sleep(5)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

A specific number has to be inputted in a text box, but the field does not get recognized. I have implemented a sleep timer so that I can log myself in and navigate to the page where the text box is located. I do not have made any complicated additions to my code and verified if there are iframes, which would block the input box.

I tried finding the element by id, name and css.selector. I've also tried using other inputs fields on the same website, which worked. I have also checked for no iframes.

Comment: Where did you get `fieldN20DA0` from?

Comment: I've used the selectorshub addon to find it and it only appears after logging in and navigating through the website.

Answer (score 0):

On the website you provided, there is only one visible input (Rechercher sur le site).

It has the name 'q' and the id 'search-field-top'. But you are searching for the input with id 'fieldN20DA0'. No elements with such id are present on the page.

You can open the Chrome Dev Tools (F12), navigate to the 'Elements' tab, and use Ctrl+F to search or test your selectors.

Another point is that you are not changing the size of the opened browser window. Your website has a bit of a strange structure.. If you change the browser window width to ~50%, the input and a couple more elements will disappear.

By default, the browser window that the driver opens is not really wide. So you have to set the [expected window size,](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/) or just maximize the window.

The following code works fine for me:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

try:
    driver.get("https://www.myguichet.lu")

    input_el = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'search-field-top')))
    input_el.send_keys("1000")
    time.sleep(5)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```